# What's the difference between typeof foo and typeof(foo) / delete bar and delete(bar), and why do we need both?

Tags: javascript

As far as I can tell, typeof foo and typeof(foo) behave the same, and the latter is much more intuitive because I can just think of it as a function.

The same for delete() .

So, is there a difference? If not, why do we need both forms?

Comment: If the latter makes you think of it as a function, perhaps it's not that intuitive after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `typeof` and `delete` are unary operators but with a big difference between the two: **`typeof` evaluates its operand and `delete` does not.** Operator precedence ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)) is useful for discussion.

**`delete` *UnaryExpression***

The delete operator does not evaluate its operand and ignores grouping operators '(' and ')' around it because they have higher precedence than `delete`. Hence `delete` could never be written as function call using the same syntax because a function call would evaluate function arguments. Delete can use property short cut or lookup syntax:

```
delete objectIdentifier.property name;  // is equivalent to
delete objectIdentifier["propertyName"]
```

In strict mode a  syntax error is generated if you try using `delete` on anything that is not a reference to an object property that includes both the property name and object.

**`typeof` *UnaryExpession***

The typeof operator evaluates its operand. If the operand expression is enclosed in parentheses, the entire expression between the parentheses is evaluated before applying `typeof` to the result. Using parentheses around an operator that can be identified using rules for operator precedence alone is redundant.

**Summary**

Using parentheses around an operand for `delete` doesn't help and is probably best avoided.

Use parentheses around a `typeof` operand to obtain the type of an expression result.

Placing parentheses around `typeof` and its operand, as in `(typeof operand)` can be useful in debugging a complex expression if operator precedence or automatic type conversions are not working as expected.

The use of parentheses around operands for `delete` and `typeof` does not create two kinds of syntax for the operators - the parentheses follow normal rules for parsing an expression.

Comment: I think you shouldn't say delete doesn't evaluate its operand, it just only accepts a certain type of operand, like a function which only accepts a certain type of argument. It just happens that almost no expression can evaluate to an existing object

Comment: The `delete` operator requires two things: a reference to an object and the name of a property to delete. Both pieces of information are contained in a property accessor expression. Evaluating its operand, say by calculating the value of an `(object.propertyName)` operand, separates the property value from where it was stored - which is of no use to `delete`.

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses are optional. `typeof` is an operator, not a function. That's like asking why do `5 + 3` and not `5 + (3)`.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it will not make a difference however, it becomes useful when you are using typeof to evaluate the type of an expression.

```
typeof(1 + ' some text');
```

returns

```
string
```

However

```
typeof 1 + ' some text';
```

returns

```
"number some text"
```

Comment: Why would someone do `typeof(1 + ' some text')`? Since you're concatenating the string value of a number and a string, the type will be always `string`. Redundant.

Comment: It's a simplified example to show the difference. Whether it is used or not is irrelevant. I was just trying to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: @AngelPolitis how about `typeof(valueA || valueB && valueC)`? what's the type of that?

Comment: Providing that the types of the values are not known beforehand, this would be a good example to add to the answer @Thomas. On the other hand, the current example fails to illustrate the usefulness of using parentheses, because evidently the type will be `string`.